# Creating a DAO Query with many One-to-Many Relationships?

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, dao

I am developing a web application with PHP and MySQL. I have an entity named, User, that has many one-to-many relationships (with other objects) within it (list of Addresses, list of Emails, list of PhoneNumbers, etc). These many addresses, emails, phone numbers are supplied to the user via junction tables in the database (user_link_addresses, user_link_emails, etc).

I am now trying to create an efficient DAO for the User entity, specifically methods readUserById($userId) and readAllUsers(). However, since I am an amateur at sql and the DAO pattern, I am having trouble creating this DAO correctly.

I have been told that it is important for network efficiency to keep your DAO to one query that reads all the information at once and then can be mapped to that entity accordingly. That does make sense, but I am having trouble generating *one* query that has the necessary information from everything and that can be mapped correctly to my entity.

Right now, I can get this information by performing multiple queries within a loop after getting the users... I just don't like that idea (and I'm sure it's not correct). Also, I know how to do joins with junction tables - just not with something this complex and that needs to be mapped correctly as well.

### TABLE NAMES AND FIELDS

TABLE: user
FIELDS: user_id, username, password

TABLE: address
FIELDS: address_id, street, city, state, zip_code, type

TABLE: email
FIELDS: email_id, email, type

TABLE: phone_number
FIELDS: phone_number_id, area_code, phone_number, type

-- JUNCTION TABLES FOR ASSOCIATIONS --

TABLE: user_link_address
FIELDS: user_id, address_id

TABLE: user_link_email
FIELDS: user_id, email_id

TABLE: user_link_phone_number
FIELDS: user_id, phone_number_id

Anyway, all help is greatly appreciated,

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's worth it to include associations within queries and sometimes it's not. There's a really neat plugin for Ruby on Rails that analyzes your application as it runs and tells you which queries should include associated models.

You could try something like:

```
SELECT *
    FROM `user` 
    INNER JOIN `user_link_addresses`
        ON `user`.id = `user_link_addresses`.user_id
    INNER JOIN `user_link_foo`
        ON `user`.id = `user_link_foo`.user_id
```

If you tell me all your table names and fields, I could help you write a more specific query.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I supplied table names and fields in my original post. I believe the supplied code that you have written will only get the address id's and foo id's associated, but not the information for each.

Comment: Are you sure about that, stjowa? Look at the example given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join -- it selects all fields from the join table.

Comment: Sorry, Eli, I wasn't very clear before... I meant that the query wouldn't give me the actual address information or foo information needed. It will give me all of the information in the tables, user_link_address and user_link_foo, but not the information in tables, address and foo (the user_link_address and user_link_foo tables are just junction tables not where the "real" information is stored). If you notice the supplied tables and fields above, it would probably explain it more.